# Flask: login using Azure

Tags: python, azure, authentication, flask

I am working on a Flask-application that requires authentication with Azure. How to set a single password to enter the application? What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

If your application requires the authentication with Azure, the best way I think is to publish it to the azure app service, then configure it to use Azure AD authentication, after configuring it, the users in your AAD tenant can login the app with their user account directly. The authentication is above the code tier, so you don't need to change your code, just follow the doc to configure it easily.

Reference:

1. [Create a Python app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash)
2. [Configure your App Service  to use Azure AD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)